# What feature is this patent protecting?

Tags: usd729508

In reference to the patent: [USD729508](https://www.google.com/patents/USD729508)

What is picture in figure 1? I can't see it. I want to know so that i don't copy it. What feature is this patent protecting?

Answer (score 0):

Go to here to see what feature it is protecting.

http://pdfpiw.uspto.gov/.piw?PageNum=0&docid=D0729508&IDKey=A324085C8B64%0D%0A&HomeUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fpatft.uspto.gov%2Fnetacgi%2Fnph-Parser%3FSect1%3DPTO2%2526Sect2%3DHITOFF%2526p%3D1%2526u%3D%25252Fnetahtml%25252FPTO%25252Fsearch-bool.html%2526r%3D3%2526f%3DG%2526l%3D50%2526co1%3DAND%2526d%3DPTXT%2526s1%3D%252522us%252Bd729508%252522%2526OS%3D%252522us%252Bd729508%252522%2526RS%3D%252522us%252Bd729508%252522

Keep in mind that it is a design patent so only the ornamental design is protected and not any functional use of it. Also, note that only the solid lines are what is protected by this patent. The dotted lines are either a) protected by a currently enforceable patent, or a patent that has since expired, or has been dedicated to the public domain without having been patented.

Comment: The dotted lines are to show unclaimed features.